# why does opencv threshold returns absurd output on a very simple image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to count seeds in an image using cv2 thresholding. The test image is below:
[image: single seed]

When I run the below code to create a mask:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('S__14278933.jpg')
#img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)

mask = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 0], 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
plt.imshow(mask)
```

I get the following mask:

[image: mask]

But ideally it should give a ***small yellow dot*** at the centre. I have tried this with other images and it works just fine.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lighting in your image seems not uniform. Try using [Adaptive Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "c6pBO.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert the image to grayscale:
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get binary image via Adaptive Thresholding :
windowSize = 31
windowConstant = 40
binaryImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold( grayImage, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
                                     cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, windowSize, windowConstant )

cv2.imshow("binaryImage", binaryImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

You might want to apply an [Area Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863948/clean-text-images-with-opencv-for-ocr-reading/) after this, though, as dark portions on the image will yield noise.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
img=cv2.imread('foto.jpg',0)
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV )[1]
```

Comment: I get the same image, pretty much.