# Clear inconsistent gray background for OCR reading

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

Some 2 years ago, I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863948/clean-text-images-with-opencv-for-ocr-reading) and got a satisfying answer. Think is, recently the script has been returning a lot of errors, over 30%, so I decided to change my approach and just ask a more generic question, thinking with the original images instead of the processed ones I used in my original question.

Here are the originals:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, these examples are slices of the original scanned documents.

The problem lies in their inconsistent quality, both in the original printing and the subsquent scanning. Sometimes the digits stand out, sometimes not. Sometimes I have a darker gray, sometimes lighter. Sometimes I get a faulty print, with white lines showing where the printer failed to put ink.

Furthermore, their font is way to "tight", as in, the digits are too close to each other, sometimes even touching, precluding me from simply separating each digit in order to clean and OCR individualy.

I've tried various approaches with OpenCV, such as various blurs:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0) # Innitial cleaning
s_thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
o_thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
ac_thres = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,5,10)
ag_thres = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 4)
```

And also connected components:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(opening, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1]  # get CC_STAT_AREA component
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 4:  
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)
gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(res, (3, 3), 0)

unsharp_image = cv2.addWeighted(res, 0.3, gaussian, 0.7, 0, res)
```

But I still get results that are inconsistent at best.

Should I change my approach? What would you guys recommend?

Comment: _slight_ gaussian blur should subdue the halftoning and moire patterns. then it's just a threshold... as for separating digits: these things are touching. OCR's job is to tolerate that.

Comment: Believe me, it does not tolerate. Sometimes I got a 4 out of a 22 (touching).

Comment: meaning that's the job/responsibility of OCR because only OCR knows what it's supposed to see. any preprocessing _can't_ fix that. I know tesseract sucks. there are freely available alternatives that blow it out of the water (easyocr).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a revisited approach to my original answer (now, implemented fully in `Python`!). I'm using the `K` channel of the [`CMYK`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color space to get a binary image. The binary image is obtained via **Otsu Thresholding** + a *little bit* of **bias**, apply a minimum area filter and then I invert the image and pass it to `teserract`.

I'm using a couple of libraries here. `imutils` for reading images in a directory, `os` for joining paths and `pytesseract` for the `OCR`. Let's see the code:

```
# Imports:
import pytesseract  # tesseract (previous installation)
import numpy as np  # numpy
import cv2  # opencv
import os  # os for paths
from imutils import paths

# Image path:
rootDir = "D:"
baseDir = "opencvImages"
subBaseDir = "numbers"

# Otsu bias:
threshBias = 1.2

# Create os-independent path:
path = os.path.join(rootDir, baseDir, subBaseDir)

# Get the test images paths:
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(path)))

# Loop over the test images and OCR them:
for imagePath in imagePaths:

    # Load the image via OpenCV:
    currentImage = cv2.imread(imagePath, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Show image:
    showImage("Current Image", currentImage)

    # Convert to float and divide by 255:
    imgFloat = currentImage.astype(np.float) / 255.

    # Calculate channel K:
    kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)

    # Convert back to uint 8:
    kChannel = (255 * kChannel).astype(np.uint8)

    # Threshold via Otsu:
    autoThresh, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # Add a little bias and threshold again:
    autoThresh = threshBias * autoThresh
    _, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, autoThresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    showImage("Current Image (Binary)", binaryImage)

    # Apply a filter area of minimum 50 pixels:
    minArea = 50
    binaryImage = areaFilter(binaryImage, minArea)
    showImage("Current Image (Filtered)", binaryImage)

    # Invert Image:
    binaryImage = 255 - binaryImage

    # Setting up tesseract:
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'  # for Windows
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(binaryImage, config=custom_config)

    # Show recognized text:
    print("Text is: " + text)
```

There are a couple of defined functions. `showImage` is just my custom function to show an image in a window via **OpenCV's High-level GUI**. After a window pop ups, press **any key** to continue evaluating the script. The `areaFilter` function is the same function from before. It applies a **minimum area filter** to the binary image:

```
# Defines a re-sizable image window:
def showImage(imageName, inputImage):
    cv2.namedWindow(imageName, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(imageName, inputImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# Applies a minimum blob area filter to an input binary image:
def areaFilter(binaryImage, minArea):
    totalComponents, labeledPixels, componentsStats, componentsCentroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage,
                                                                                                            connectivity=4)
    remaining_comp_labels = [i for i in range(1, totalComponents) if componentsStats[i][4] >= minArea]
    outImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledPixels, remaining_comp_labels) == True, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
    return outImage
```

Let's check out some results. For the first image, this is the `K` (black) channel only:

[image]

This is the pre-filtered binary image (Otsu + bias):

[image]

This is the filtered image:

[image]

`Teserract` returns this:

```
Text is: 820065084250
```

The `strings` returned for every image, according to `Teserract`, are:

| Tesseract OCR |
| --- |
| 820065084250 |
| 930023482930 |
| 820065085833 |
| 930023485203 |
| 820065072022 |
| 930023485564 |
| 820065084802 |
| 820065084691 |
| 820065084730 |
| 930023445422 |
| 820065084551 |
| 82006507 1840 |

Note that the `2` in `820065084551` is successfully recognized, even though the number is partly cut. There's white space in the last string probably because the numbers on the image are a little bit separated. You can post-process the string to remove these white spaces.

Comment: Why the rectangle is getting wider?

Comment: Which rectangle?

Comment: the one you posted  fourth images

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Are you referring to the images in my answer? There are only three images, and all of them have the same width.

Comment: The next image The strings returned for every image, according to Teserract, are:

Comment: You mean the table? The table is rendered by Stack Overflow, I'm seeing all the data in one same-width column.

Comment: Funny story, since my original question I've actualy read a couple of books on C++, and tried your orginal answer adapted to python. I'll implement this one with the code and test on a much larger sample.